# Only Allow 1 user to Remote Desktop at a time (Windows 2019)

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp, users

By default Windows 2019 allows 2 users to remote desktop at one time.  Is there a way to restrict this even further to allow only 1 remote desktop user at a time?
I tried the following tutorial, however I'm still able to remote desktop with 2 different users at the same time.
https://support.managed.com/kb/a1816/how-to-enable-disable-multiple-rdp-sessions-in-windows-2012-2012-r2-2016-and-2019.aspx

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if restricting RDP access to one user at this time is possible for Windows 2019.  However, I came up with a workaround that works great.
I created a scheduled task that will log off all other users when a user logs in. This way only one user can be logged in at a time.
The scheduled task runs a batch script to accomplish this, here is the batch script if anyone is interested:

```
query session >session.txt  
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2,3," %%i in (session.txt) DO if not %USERNAME%==%%i logoff %%j  
del session.txt
```

Comment: why would you like to do this?

Comment: I think this will only work if `%USERNAME%` is in the Administrators group; otherwise `logoff.exe` wil fail to log off other users.